# How to insert a java list of lists into MySQL Database?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Can't seem to find a way to do this properly.

I've created a database using JDBC to store information saved as a list of lists into a table:

```
public void CreateDB() {

    Connection connection = DButil.connectionToDatabaseMySQL();
    Statement statement = null;

    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS IUCN_DB");
        statement.execute("USE IUCN_DB");
        statement.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS IUCN_List"
                +
                "(speciesID int auto_increment NOT NULL,\n"
                + "className CHAR(255) NOT NULL,\n"
                + "sciName CHAR(255) NOT NULL,\n"
                + "comName CHAR(255) NOT NULL,\n"
                + "regionsFound CHAR(255) NOT NULL,\n"
                + "redlistCate CHAR(255) NOT NULL,\n"
                + "popuTrend CHAR(255) NOT NULL,\n"
                + "actionPlan CHAR(255) NOT NULL,\n"
                + "PRIMARY KEY (speciesID)\n"
                + ") ENGINE=INNODB;\n"
                + "\n");
        System.out.println("Database and table created successfully");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a java list of lists which stores data in this format:

```
 Class Name, Scientific Name, Common Name, Regions Found, Red List Category, Population Trend, Action Plan
[[CHONDRICHTHYES, Sphyrna lewini, Scalloped Hammerhead, Europe, Data Deficient, Decreasing, No Action],
[CHONDRICHTHYES, Sphyrna mokarran, Great Hammerhead, Europe, Data Deficient, Decreasing, No Action]]
```

I'd imagine I'd need to implement something like this:

```
for sublist in mainlist{
      
  INSERT INTO IUCN_List (className,sciName,comName,regionsFound,redlistCate,popuTrend,actionPlan) VALUES (sublist);
      
      }
```

However that hasn't worked for me.

Anything to point me in the right direction?

Comment: It sounds like you should start by replacing your list of lists with a `List<Species>`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Say I did that, how would I iterate through the list so that it inserted the values to the database in groups of 7?

Comment: research for Jdbc PreparedStatement. Just a loop to do it

Comment: Also, is this for a class? What constraints do you have? Normally, I'd just throw Spring Data at it, but I suspect you might be focusing on lower-level operations.